# Сохранение изменений в базе данных MSSQL с помощью DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

В общем, работа с бд MSSQL, WPF. Вместо сложного пути подключения через код и написания запросов в коде был выбран лёгкий вариант - Добавление источника данных через графический интерфейс. После добавления источников данных, нужная БД просто переносилась Drag & Drop на форму и отображала данные.

Снизу отображена лишь синхронизация DataGridView и TextBox, которые дублируют данные.

Нужно, что бы по нажатию кнопки изменения, которые происходили в DataGridView, сохранялись в самой базе данных. Буду благодарен

```
namespace OldGoodEnterprice

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{



    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        OldGoodEnterprice.OGE_Base_1DataSet oGE_Base_1DataSet = ((OldGoodEnterprice.OGE_Base_1DataSet)(this.FindResource("oGE_Base_1DataSet")));
        // Загрузка данные в таблицу staff
        OldGoodEnterprice.OGE_Base_1DataSetTableAdapters.staffTableAdapter oGE_Base_1DataSetstaffTableAdapter = new OldGoodEnterprice.OGE_Base_1DataSetTableAdapters.staffTableAdapter();
        oGE_Base_1DataSetstaffTableAdapter.Fill(oGE_Base_1DataSet.staff);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource staffViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("staffViewSource")));
        staffViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        // Загрузка данные в таблицу staff_salary_mounth
        OldGoodEnterprice.OGE_Base_1DataSetTableAdapters.staff_salary_mounthTableAdapter oGE_Base_1DataSetstaff_salary_mounthTableAdapter = new OldGoodEnterprice.OGE_Base_1DataSetTableAdapters.staff_salary_mounthTableAdapter();
        oGE_Base_1DataSetstaff_salary_mounthTableAdapter.Fill(oGE_Base_1DataSet.staff_salary_mounth);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource staff_salary_mounthViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("staff_salary_mounthViewSource")));
        staff_salary_mounthViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();


    }

    private void Button_Update_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //кнопка обновления данных
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter apd = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        apd.Update(dt);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Вам в dataset нужно дополнить команды. У вас скорее всего есть запрос на select. Нужно тот же адаптер дополнить на update. Тогда должно заработать apd.Update(dt); Если изменения проходят в DataGridView то он их сам помечает автоматически как измененные, и при выполнении отправляет по адаптеру соответствующие команды. Если строка была добавлена то выполнить команду insert, если изменена то update. Если хотите менять вне DataGridView то нужно немного дописать обработку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]